# Add table of contents to RTF document

Tags: rtf, tableofcontents

I am trying to generate a RTF document by hand and eventually will do it programtically. I plan to improve pyRTF so that it can generate "Table of contents", which I think it can't.

I am not able to use RTF controls words (\tc, \tcf and \tcl.) to generate a TOC. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283(office.10).aspx gives details about TOC but I couldn't find or make any example RTF which have a TOC.

So is there a simple sample showing a RTF with TOC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am creating a Table with hyperlinks to bookmarks to title on various pages.

e.g.

```
'{\\field{\\*\\fldinst  HYPERLINK \\\\l "%s"} {\\fldrslt %s}}'%(bookmark, text)
"{\\field{\\*\\fldinst  PAGEREF %s }}"%bookmark
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\adeflang1045
{\fonttbl {\f0\fsserif\fcharset238 Verdana;}}

\titlepage\line\line\line\line\line
{\pard \s1\f0\b\scaps\fs80\qc
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Title Page\line\fs30\scaps0\b0 go to Table of Contents}}
\par}

\page{\*\bkmkstart page2}{\*\bkmkend page2}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page \chpgn}}\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page3}{\*\bkmkend page3}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page \chpgn}}\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page4}{\*\bkmkend page4}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page \chpgn}}\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page5}{\*\bkmkend page5}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page \chpgn}}\par}

\page{\*\bkmkstart toc}{\*\bkmkend toc}{\pard\sa1000\f0\fs50\b\qc{\field{\*\fldinst TOC}{\fldrslt Table of Contents}}\par}
{\pard\f0\fs28\fi0\trowd\cellx8000\cellx8600
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page2"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page2}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page2}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page3"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page3}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page3}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page4"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page4}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page4}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page5"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page5}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page5}}\cell\row
\par}
}
```

Comment: This code snippet goes into an infinite loop on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrates a well formed TOC

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\adeflang1045
{\fonttbl {\f0\fsserif\fcharset238 Verdana;}}
\titlepage\line\line\line\line\line
{\pard
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\ul0 Title Page\line go to Table of Contents}}
\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page2}{\*\bkmkend page2}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page3}{\*\bkmkend page3}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page4}{\*\bkmkend page4}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page5}{\*\bkmkend page5}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart toc}{\*\bkmkend toc}{\pard\sa1000\f0\fs50\b\qc{\field{\*\fldinst TOC}{\fldrslt Table of Contents}}\par}
{\pard\f0\fs28\fi0\trowd\cellx8000\cellx8600
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page2"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page2}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page2}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page3"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page3}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page3}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page4"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page4}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page4}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page5"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page5}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page5}}\cell\row
\par}
}
```