# How to add table of contents(TOC) to RTF document?

Tags: rtf

I have many tables, I want to generate a table of contents(includling table titles) programtically.But I couldn't find or make any example RTF which have a TOC.

So is there a simple example showing a RTF with TOC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the rtf specs: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading62

> The \tc control word introduces a table of contents entry, which can
> be used to build the actual table of contents. The \tcn control word
> marks a table of contents entry that will not have a page number
> associated with it; this is used in place of \tc for such entries.
> Table of contents entries are destinations, and they have the
> following syntax:
>
> '{' \tc | \tcn (\tcf? & \tcl?) + '}'
>
> As with index entries, text that is not formatted as hidden with the
> \v character-formatting control word is put into the document. The
> following control words can also be used in this destination.
>
> **Control words:**
>
> **\tcfN**     Type of table being compiled. N is mapped by existing Microsoft software to a letter between A and Z (the default is 67,
> which maps to C, used for tables of contents).
>
> **\tclN**     Level number (the default is 1).

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would add a practical example as the documentation is not overly helpful to the way my mind works although it is all covered!

`<xsl:text>{\tc\fs0\cf4 Report Details}</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Report Details\cell</xsl:text>`

to mark the item, and then display

`<xsl:text>\page Table of Contents\line</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>{\field{\*\fldinst {\\TOC \\f \\h}}}</xsl:text>`

open in Word

using Ctrl-A (select all) => F9 as the TOC has to be activated.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I finally found the answer to this question. You need to use the bookmark feature to get a table of contents. See this question [Add table of contents to RTF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097358/add-table-of-contents-to-rtf-document)