# Table of Contents (TOC) in a RTF document. Formatting problem with PAGEREF

Tags: vb.net, formatting, rtf, tableofcontents

I am referring to a very well done example reported in this post:

[Add table of contents to RTF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097358/add-table-of-contents-to-rtf-document/78148649#78148649)

in which is shown how to write a Table Of Contents with RTF specifications:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\adeflang1045
{\fonttbl {\f0\fsserif\fcharset238 Verdana;}}
\titlepage\line\line\line\line\line
{\pard
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\ul0 Title Page\line go to Table of Contents}}
\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page2}{\*\bkmkend page2}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page3}{\*\bkmkend page3}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page4}{\*\bkmkend page4}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart page5}{\*\bkmkend page5}\line\line\line\line\line{\pard\f0\fs80\b\scaps\qc\sa10000{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "toc"} {\fldrslt Page}} \chpgn\par}
\page{\*\bkmkstart toc}{\*\bkmkend toc}{\pard\sa1000\f0\fs50\b\qc{\field{\*\fldinst TOC}{\fldrslt Table of Contents}}\par}
{\pard\f0\fs28\fi0\trowd\cellx8000\cellx8600
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page2"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page2}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page2}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page3"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page3}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page3}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page4"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page4}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page4}}\cell\row
\pard\intbl\ql {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \\l "page5"} {\fldrslt\ul0 Link to anchor #page5}}\cell\pard\intbl\qr {\field{\*\fldinst PAGEREF page5}}\cell\row
\par}
}
```

I applied exactly the same structure and it's quite all ok but I still have a problem. In the TOC, the second column that point to "PAGEREF pageX" is not available to any change of style. I am not able to change the font and the dimension. It always sets to the default text style and size. How can this be edited?

I tried formatting the text between {} with RTF syntax but nothing changed.